# Arraylist: add text to item with button click

Tags: android, button, arraylist

I have a Arrayadpter with a textfield and a button. Each time I press the button the textfield should add 1. the problem is that I lose my entry when I scroll out of the screen. I know that I should use a CheckForUpdateListener or something like that, but I do not know how to implement it. Thanks for help:

```
public class startseitenAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<getraenkeObjekt> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
int anzahl;
ArrayList<getraenkeObjekt> data = new ArrayList<getraenkeObjekt>();

public startseitenAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<getraenkeObjekt> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    UserHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.getraenkename = (TextView)  

 holder.getraenkename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    holder.anzahl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    final UserHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int summand = 1;
            Log.d("Adapter", "plus " + summand + " Position " + position);
            MySQLiteHelper m = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
            final int globid = position;
            int anzahl = m.wertAenderung(globid, summand);
            finalHolder.anzahl.setText(anzahl + " ");
           }
    });




    getraenkeObjekt drink = data.get(position);

    holder.getraenkename.setText(drink.getname());
    holder.anzahl.setText(drink.getanzahl()+" ");


    return convertView;
}


static class UserHolder {
    TextView getraenkename;
    TextView anzahl;
    Button plus;
}
```

Comment: Post you Activity@user3336320

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ArrayList or array to hold the the last updated values... Whenever you scroll down or up, your your view object overrides with new values which old values and won't be stored anywhere. You have to store them in array list or something like that.

Let's say you are clicking 4th rows button object. Your 4th rows textview should be changed so put `ArrayList.set(4,"updatedvalue");` and when you scroll down or up get the value from the array list with the position coming... As `holder.textview.setText(ArrayList.get(position))`

This will do what you needed...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please do not use text speak in your answers